# UnauthorizedAccessException while accessing Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.Site on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, iis, wix, windows-8.1

Does someone get any hint for accessing `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.Sites` collection on Win8.1 (and Win8) if the user got no right on file `"%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config"` ?

Because the user will get `UnauthorizedAccessException` in this case...

More largely, on Win8 you can get into trouble on any `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager` property if your user has no right on `"%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config"`.

This works perfectly on Win7, W2008 and W2012..

HowTo: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration

I need this in a WiX c# Custom Action launched in 'client' step (while in UI) to browse installed Web sites and applications on them for unicity check on new WebApplication name.

Of course, I cant find any relevant answer for this while googling. There are only a few answers out and they hint to launch with elevated privilege or change the rights on the folder, witch of course is not feasible in a regular user setup UI process.

Ex: http://sharepointyankee.com/2011/03/30/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-filename-redirection-config/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for information, it seems to be no way to get rid of this...

So I choose to modify my Custom Action to ignore this case by catching UnauthorizedAccessException and still set success for unicity check and return a success for the CA call.

In this case in client step I won't get a failure, with counterpart that I can't get the real result of the unicity check. But I get the result if it wont fail with UnauthorizedAccessException and I can spawn a dialog to the user inviting him to change the site name.

Then in server step where by the way this check ever works I do the same test to be able to fail the setup with a clear message if the website is not unique.
This is not the best for the user who must then restart the setup to change the site name but it works and avoid strange failures by trying to create two websites with the same name.